# Is there a nonzero function orthogonal to $\sqrt{x}$ over $[0, 1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality

Does there exist a function $f(x) \in C([0, 1])$, where $f \neq 0$, such that $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \ f(x) \ dx = 0?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{x}\in L^2(0,1)$, so there are plenty of continuous functions orthogonal to $\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1)$.
By considering the shifted Legendre polynomials $Q_n(x)= P_n(2x-1)$ we have a complete orthogonal base of $L^2(0,1)$, $$\int_{0}^{1}Q_n(x)Q_m(x)\,dx = \frac{\delta(n,m)}{2n+1}\tag{1}$$
and by Rodrigues' formula 
$$ Q_n(x) = \frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x(x-1)\right)^n. \tag{2}$$
In particular, by integration by parts the Fourier-Legendre series expansion of $\sqrt{x}$ is given by
$$ \sqrt{x}\stackrel{L_2}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2(-1)^n}{(1-2n)(2n+3)}\,Q_n(x)\tag{3} $$
and obviously $\sqrt{x}$ and $a_0+a_1 x+\ldots+a_n x^n$ are orthogonal on $(0,1)$ iff
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a_k}{k+\frac{3}{2}} = 0.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Is it possible to use this construction to determine a single polynomial orthogonal to $\sqrt{x + b}$ for any choice of $b$?

Comment: @S.J.: of course, there is little to adjust. On the other hand, you cannot have a non-zero continuous function orthogonal to each function of the form $\sqrt{x+b}$ with $b\geq 0$: this is an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 3):

What about $\;f(x)=1-\frac43\sqrt x\;$ ?

Answer (score 3):

You could also try an ansatz of $f(x)=Ax+B$. One such that works is $B=3/2, \; A=-5/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be any continuous function on $[0,1]$ for which $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\sqrt{t}dt \ne 0$, and which is not a scalar multiple of $\sqrt{x}$. For example, $f(x)=1$. Define a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ by
$$
      g(x) = f(x)-\frac{\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\sqrt{t}dt}{\int_{0}^{1}tdt}\sqrt{x}
$$
Then $g\ne 0$ and
$$
           \int_{0}^{1}g(x)\sqrt{x}dx =0.
$$